# Cannot find MainActivity.java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, main-activity

I am currently writing an Android App using Android Studio 1.2. However, i cannot find MainActivity.java file in it.

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Al

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: Thank you all the replies.

When I follow the path, app then java, what I can see next is com.a, and that's it. I cannot open that file (com.a) at all. What I want to do is to import different widgets and properties to my app.

Would be grateful if someone can solve it out.

Thanks!

Comment: com.a sounds like a package to me, does it have a package icon to the left of it? If so, you need to right click and select New and then the file type you wish to create. (You should probably rename that package too!)

Comment: What should I click after right click? Kindly advise @JoeBirch

Comment: While creating a new project, make sure you click on **"Empty Activity"** instead of no activity

Answer (score 1):

I have Android Studio 1.2 too. In the left side:

- Choose *1: Project* if it isn´t already open.
- Then choose `app`, then `java`.
- Then choose `com.username.project`.
- Finally choose `MainActivity.java`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary that your file is named MainActivity.java. That is the default name. If you created the Java file with another name while making the project then that will be your main Activity file. It will have the name you gave while making the project.

Otherwise just create a new activity and enter its name in the Manifest file to make it the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you create new project select Blank Activity. MainActivity file is in Android -> app -> java -> your.package.name

Answer (score 0):

Inside of android folder navigate to

`app --> src --> java --> com --> "your app name"`